# Does PowerShell have something similar to the Perl abbrev() function

Tags: powershell

So in Perl, there is a function call abbrev() that given a list of keywords, returns a hash mapping all the minimally abbreviations to their keyword:

```
@keywords = {"this", "and", "that"}
%AbbevList = abbrev(@keywords);
```

This would return a Hash like this:

```
thi => "this"
this => "this"
tha => "that"
that => "that"
a => "and"
an => "and"
and => "and"
```

In Perl, this allowed me to take user abbreviations for my keywords and easily map them correctly to the "real" keyword as long as the user's input was minimally unique.

Does PowerShell have anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in that I know of, but that's not to say you can't have it.

```
 function abbrevs {
     param ([string[]]$list)
     $abbrs = @{}
     $list |% {
         foreach ($i in 1..($_.length)){
             if (($list -like "$(($_.substring(0,$i)) + '*')").count -eq 1){
             $abbrs[$_.substring(0,$i)] = $_
             }
         }
     }
 $abbrs
 } 



  $abbr_table = abbrevs @("this","that","and")

  $abbr_table.getenumerator() | sort name | fl



 Name  : a
 Value : and

 Name  : an
 Value : and

 Name  : and
 Value : and

 Name  : tha
 Value : that

 Name  : that
 Value : that

 Name  : thi
 Value : this

 Name  : this
 Value : this
```

Comment: Thank you not just for the answer, but for the working code as well.  I am a newb and still learning to "think PowerShell".  A second solution that occurred to me . . . -match threw the keys "^$userResponse".  If I get more than one match, I then have the collection for a "which did you mean" error prompt . . . if I only have one, use it.  Interesting language . . . it is going to take me awhile to get my head around.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters in powershell can be specified in this fashion. You only need to specify enough letters to be unique. Commands and keywords need to be fully specified though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate implementation:

```
function abbrev( [string[]]$words ) {
  $abbrevs = @{}
  foreach( $word in $words ) {
    1..$word.Length |
      % { $word.Substring( 0, $_ ) } |
      ? { @($words -match "^$_").Length -eq 1 } |
      % { $abbrevs.$_ = $word }
  }

  $abbrevs
}
```

Similar to mjolinor's approach, it checks each substring on each word, adding those that match only the current word to the hashtable.

As Frank points out in a comment, you can also simply save all the matches, and use non-unique entries to disambiguate between options:

```
$keywords = 'this','and','that'
$abbrevs = @{}
foreach( $word in $keywords ) {
  1..$word.Length |
    % { $word.Substring( 0, $_ ) } |
    % { $abbrevs.$_ = @($words -match "^$_") }
}

$abbrevs

Name  Value
----  -----
an    {and}
that  {that}
and   {and}
tha   {that}
thi   {this}
t     {this, that}
th    {this, that}
a     {and}
this  {this}
```

As Oisin points out, this matching is already built into powershell:

```
function f( [switch]$this, [switch]$that ) {
  if( $this ) { 'this' }
  if( $that ) { 'that' }
}

> f -thi
this

> f -th
f : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'th' is ambiguous.
Possible matches include: -this -that.
At line:1 char:2
+ f <<<<  -th
    + CategoryInfo      : InvalidArgument: (:) [f], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,f
```